# NestJS - database entities is returned from the backend instead of DTO

Tags: javascript, entity, nestjs, dto

I am new to the NestJs and i am stuck on problem with returning response entity from my backend.

The problem is that even when i return Promise-PostDTO-. It's still returns Post entity from database. With all the properties and nestjs ignore return type.

Do you know where can be problem? I though that automatic conversion works in both ways.
Maybe problem is in returning Promise and not PostDTO.

I hope that someone can help me.
Thanks

The code below.

post.entity.ts

```
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export default class Post {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  perex: string;

  @Column()
  content: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

post.dto.ts

```
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { Exclude, Expose } from 'class-transformer';
@Exclude()
export class PostDTO {
  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  readonly title: string;
  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  readonly perex: string;
  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  readonly content: string;
}
```

post.repository.ts

```
import { Repository, EntityRepository } from 'typeorm';
import Post from './post.entity';
@EntityRepository(Post)
export class PostRepository extends Repository<Post> {}
```

post.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import Post from './post.entity';
import { PostRepository } from './post.repository';
import { PostDTO, PostRO } from './post.dto';

@Injectable()
export class PostService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Post) private readonly postRepository: PostRepository,
  ) {}
  async createPost(post: PostDTO): Promise<PostDTO> {
    return await this.postRepository.save(post);
  }
}
```

post.controller.ts

```
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Post,
  Body,
  UseInterceptors,
  ClassSerializerInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { PostService } from './post.service';
import { PostDTO } from './post.dto';
@Controller('post')
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
export class PostController {
  constructor(private readonly postService: PostService) {}

  @Post()
  async createPost(@Body() post: PostDTO): Promise<PostDTO> {
    return await this.postService.createPost(post);
  }
}
```

Based on the Jay McDoniel's answer i refactor my code to this.

I used custom nestjs interceptor that converts classes.

```
import {
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
  ExecutionContext,
  CallHandler,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

interface ClassType<T> {
  new (): T;
}

@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<Partial<T>, T> {
  constructor(private readonly classType: ClassType<T>) {}

  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    call$: CallHandler<Partial<T>>,
  ): Observable<T> {
    return call$.handle().pipe(map(data => plainToClass(this.classType, data)));
  }
}
```

I also refactor my DTO with class-transformer package.

```
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Exclude, Expose } from 'class-transformer';
@Exclude()
export class ArticleDTO {
  @Expose()
  @ApiProperty({ required: true })
  @IsString()
  readonly title: string;
  @Expose()
  @ApiProperty({ required: true })
  @IsString()
  readonly perex: string;
  @Expose()
  @ApiProperty({ required: true })
  @IsString()
  readonly content: string;
}
```

Usage of the new iterceptor in my controller.

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ArticleService } from './article.service';
import { ArticleDTO } from './dto/article.dto';
import { TransformInterceptor } from 'src/transform.interceptor';
@Controller('articles')
@UseInterceptors(new TransformInterceptor(ArticleDTO))
export class ArticleController {
  constructor(private readonly articleService: ArticleService) {}
  @Get()
  async getAllPosts(): Promise<ArticleDTO[]> {
    return await this.articleService.getAllPosts();
  }

  @Post()
  async createPost(@Body() post: ArticleDTO): Promise<ArticleDTO> {
    return await this.articleService.createPost(post);
  }
}
```

After these code updates it works as expected, so it returns DTO instead of DB Entity.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript is a very useful dev tool to work with, but there are times where things fall through gaps. In this case, you're telling Typescript that `PostController#createPost` will return a `PostDTO`, which as mentioned above has properties of `title`, `perex`, and `content`. Now, when you run the query for `this.postRepository.save()` that method returns a `Post` object, which has `id`, `title,` `perex`, `content`, and `createdAt`. Because a `Post` object has the same fields (and a few more) as `PostDTO`, Typescript does not tell you you aren't returning the same object. Similarly, these types disappear at runtime, because Typescript is a development tool, not a runtime (unless you're using Deno), so all that the JavaScript sees is `return await this.postRepository.save()` and that's what's going to be sent back to the caller.

How you can get around this is

1. Use a local variable and remove the `id` and `createdAt` fields
2. Use a serializer like `class-transformer` or `MarshalTS` to transform the result to the desired object.